# Explicit 3-cocycle of group cohomology of dihedral group and generalization to other semidirect products

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

The dihedral group $D_8$ can be presented as $(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2)\rtimes _{\rho}\mathbb{Z}_2$, where the last factor acts on $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ as
$$
\rho_1(a,b)=(b,a) \ .
$$
I am interested in explicit 3-cocycle of the group cohomology $H^3(D_8,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$. Let me be more explicit about the presentation I would like to see, and which part of the group-cohomology I want to represent. Given a manifold $X$ a class in $H^1(X,\mathbb{D}_8)$ (the $H^1$ is the only one existing with non-abelian coefficients) can be decomposed into classes $A\in H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $(B_1,B_2)\in H_{\rho}^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2)$ (this denotes the cohomology with local coefficients, understanding $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z_2}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ module for $\rho$). I know that there exist a (unique) order-two class in $H^3(D_8,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ which when pulled back using $A, (B_1,B_2)$ produces
$$
A\cup B_1\cup B_2
$$
where the cup product is the standard one for $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I think this is essentially the class corresponding to the subgroup $H^1_{\rho}(\mathbb{Z}_2,H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}))\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Does this make sense?

I look for a generalization replacing $\mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_n$ with $n$ even. $\rho$ still acts as $\rho_1(a,b)=(b,a)$ and there is a group $(\mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_n)\rtimes _{\rho}\mathbb{Z}_2$. A natural guess is to take the $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ subgroup and thus write something like
$$
A\cup(n/2) B_1\cup (n/2)B_2
$$
but I think this is not correct, since this is actually the pull back of a class of the direct product $\mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

If it would be easier it is also fine to provide the class algebraically in group-cohomology.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found a solution to my question for any semidirect product $G_1\rtimes _{\rho}G_2$, $G_1,G_2$ abelian. Essentially I was looking for the class of $H^3(B G_1\rtimes _{\rho}G_2,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ corresponding to the subgroup $H^1_{\rho}(BG_2,H^2(BG_1,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}))$. A class in this group is a twisted homomorphsim $\mu: G_1\rightarrow H^2(BG_1,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, where the target can be understood as the group of alternating bicharacters on $G_1$. Given $A\in H^1(X,G_2)$ one can check that $\mu(A) \in H^1_{\rho}(X,H^2(BG_1,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}))$, and it can be used to construct a sensible cup product which gives a class $\mu(A)\cup B\cup B\in H^3(X,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ for any $B\in H^1_{\rho}(X,G_1)$